# Dying Kernel while accessing IBM DB2 database with SQL Magic

Tags: python, db2, kernel

I'm using a Anaconda Jupyter Notebook.

After installing these libraries:

```
!pip install --force-reinstall ibm_db==3.1.0 ibm_db_sa==0.3.3
!pip uninstall sqlalchemy==1.4 -y && pip install sqlalchemy==1.3.24
!pip install ipython-sql
```

Then loading the sql extention by running this code:

```
%load_ext sql
```

After which i created a connection string to connect to the Db2 database:

```
%sql ibm_db_sa://abc:password@mydatabase.databases.appdomain.cloud:3/BLUDB?security=SSL
```

But running that last code, the python kernel keeps dying. Please help!

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify (don't use comments because they are not searchable).Which Python version and bitness? Which op system? Which browser? Do you have any Db2 products installed locally? Have you tried with the current version of ibm_db (today that is version 3.1.3? Are you able to connect to the database without using python (for example at the operating system shell, using db2cli (needs db2dsdriver.cfg to be configured with the DSN details first). Before running pip did you use `pip install --upgrade pip` as required by the docs?